# Vue 3 Assign value to computed property from array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, iteration, computed-properties

I have a problem assigning the correct value to my computed property. I want the computed property answerHistory to return correctAnswer for the current question.

This is my JSON

```
[
  {
    "quizID": 1,
    "questionID": 1,
    "question": "What color/colour is a polar bears skin?",
    "correct_answer": "Black",
    "answers": [
      "White",
      "Pink",
      "Black",
      "Green"
    ],
    "selectedAnswer": null,
  },
  {
    "quizID": 1,
    "questionID": 2,
    "question": "What are rhinos horn made of?",
    "correct_answer": "Keratin",
    "answers": [
      "Keratin",
      "Bone",
      "Ivory",
      "Skin"
    ],
    "selectedAnswer": null,
  },
  {
    "quizID": 1,
    "questionID": 3,
    "question": "What do you call a baby bat?",
    "correct_answer": "Pup",
    "answers": [
      "Cub",
      "Chick",
      "Kid",
      "Pup"
    ],
    "selectedAnswer": null,
  }
]
```

This is my computed property

```
const answerHistory = computed(() => {
  return questions.value.map(question => {
    return {
      quizID: question.quizID,
      questionID: question.questionID,
      selectedAnswer: question.selectedAnswer,
      correctAnswer: correctAnswer.value,
    }
  })
})
```

Everything works fine except **correctAnswer.value**, it's because I have this code that changes my JSON data for each question. But because **correctAnswer.value** is not in **data**, but inside **computed**.

```
const setAnswer = (e) => {
  questions.value.selectedAnswer = e.target.value
  if (questions.value[questionIndex.value].selectedAnswer == questions.value[questionIndex.value].correct_answer) {
    answerHistory.value[questionIndex.value].is_answer_correct = true;
    correctAnswers.value++
  } else {
    answerHistory.value[questionIndex.value].is_answer_correct = false;
    wrongAnswers.value++
  }
  e.target.value = null
}
```

But I don't want to change my JSON data. I want to make the computed property and control the changes there. The problem is this

```
answerHistory.value[questionIndex.value].is_answer_correct = true;
```

changes "is_correct_answer" for all answers, not only the current one.

This is the whole code, however, it does not work on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-bush-j4ne7n?file=/src/App.vue

It was quite complicated for me to explain it so if you don't understand my question let me know and I will write more details. Thank you